# Update a huge table with values from another table using multiple like condition

Tags: oracle, updates

I have a table `REVERSE` with columns as

```
ID ORG_ID FULL_ID DATE_REV
-- ------ ------- --------
X1 11%    NULL
X2 22%    NULL
X3 33%    NULL
X4 44%    NULL
X5 55%    NULL
```

I have another table `MASTER` with columns as

```
FULL_ORG DATE 
-------- --------
11ABC    20190101
22DEF    20190101
33GHI    20190101
44XYZ    20190101
55MNO    20190101
```

How can i find the FULL_ORG and corresponding DATE value from `MASTER` using the ORG_ID from `REVERSE`, and update in the FULL_ID field and DATE_REV field correspondingly.

Please help..

The result should be as below.

```
TXN ORG_TXN FULL_ORG DATE
--- ------- -------- --------
  1 11%     11ABC    20190101
  2 22%     22DEF    20190101
  3 33%     33GHI    20190101
  4 44%     44XYZ    20190101
  5 55%     55MNO    20190101
```

Comment: What is the logic that determines which row in `MASTER` joins to which row in `REVERSE`?

Comment: ORG_ID in REVERSE should join with the FULL_ORG in MASTER. Query should be : UPDATE REVERSE SET (FULL_ID ,DATE_REV) = (SELECT FULL_ORG, DATE FROM MASTER INNER JOIN REVERSE ON (FULL_ORG LIKE ORG_ID))  WHERE ID='X1' . This is working for me if i add the condition as ID='X1'. But i have bulk data and if i remove this condition query will be hung.

Comment: If there are two rows in the MASTER table starting with the same two digits, which row should be used to update the row in the REVERSE table?

Comment: That is unique. Both ORG_ID in Reverse and FULL_ORG in Master is unique.

Comment: Thing is, full_orgs `11ABC` and `11DEF` are unique. What prevents a second full_org starting with `11` from being added into the table?

Comment: Is always the *number prefix* in both keys of the same length? Would you want to match e.g. `11%`   and  `112ABC`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option you might consider:

```
SQL> with
  2  rev (id, org_id) as
  3    (select 'X1', '11%' from dual union all
  4     select 'X2', '22%' from dual union all
  5     select 'X3', '33%' from dual union all
  6     select 'X4', '44%' from dual union all
  7     select 'X5', '55%' from dual
  8    ),
  9  mas (full_org, c_date) as
 10    (select '11ABC', 20190101 from dual union all
 11     select '22DEF', 20190101 from dual union all
 12     select '33GHI', 20190101 from dual union all
 13     select '44XYZ', 20190101 from dual union all
 14     select '55MNO', 20190101 from dual
 15    )
 16  select regexp_substr(r.id, '\d+$') txn,
 17         r.org_id,
 18         m.full_org,
 19         m.c_date
 20  from rev r join mas m on regexp_substr(r.org_id, '^\d+') = regexp_substr(m.full_org, '^\d+');

TXN      ORG FULL_     C_DATE
-------- --- ----- ----------
1        11% 11ABC   20190101
2        22% 22DEF   20190101
3        33% 33GHI   20190101
4        44% 44XYZ   20190101
5        55% 55MNO   20190101

SQL>
```

Comment: The intention is to get FULL_ID which we don't know. For Ex:- FULL_ORG (say '11ABC') from master is not known to us and need to find out by using like condition in ORG_ID in REVERSE table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to update the data in REVERSE table:

```
MERGE INTO REVERSE R 
USING MASTER M 
ON ( REGEXP_SUBSTR(R.ORG_ID, '^\d+') = REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.FULL_ORG, '^\d+') )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
SET R.FULL_ID = M.FULL_ORG,
R."DATE" = M."DATE"
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e708ba44ddf1a3f9b7d14301618387c)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If your `ORG_ID` has a fixed length (e.g. two digits and a `%` character) you may simple join of a `substr`ing of the keys

```
select r.org_id,
   m.full_org,
   m.c_date
from reverse r join master m 
on  substr(r.org_id,1,2) =  substr(m.full_org,1,2)
```

This will be the most *performant* method, but fails if the key length changes

Comment: ORG_ID is of variable length.

Comment: Can you **limit** the length?